# Android EventBus - onEventMainThread is never used

Tags: android, event-bus

I'm trying to listen an event on my activity, but Android Studio says to me that the method `onEventMainThread` is never used, and obviously it never goes inside it...

I don't know why because I registered the activity on `EventBus` doing the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.telegram_conversations_activity);
    EventBus.getDefault().registerSticky(this);
    //...
}

public void onEventMainThread(TdApi.UpdateFile file) {
    Toast.makeText(TelegramConversationsActivity.this,"ey",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on the method instead of calling it onEventMainThread.

@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

// UI updates must run on MainThread
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(TdApi.UpdateFile file) {
    Toast.makeText(TelegramConversationsActivity.this,"ey",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);    
    super.onStop();
}
```